# change background of v-carousel delimiters

Tags: carousel, vuetify.js

how to change a background color of dot controls in v-carousel?

this is for vuetify

```
<v-carousel
 hide-controls
 :cycle="false"
 light
>
 <v-carousel-item>
```

```
// not work

  .v-carousel__controls
    background blue !important
  .v-carousel__controls__item
    color red !important
```

the class not work

Answer (score 1):

I found that removing the scoped attribute did the trick, so this works:

```
<style> /* <-- remove scoped here if you have it*/
   .v-carousel__controls{
       background: blue !important
   }
   .v-carousel__controls__item{
      color: red !important
   }
</style>
```

Comment: i not using scoped for that, i solved creating a upper css class and modify inside, bit, thanks

Comment: Why does Vuetify make things like this so difficult?? :s